# php save array value in a session while looping

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach, session-cookies

I have an array like so

```
[0] => Mike
[1] => 933
[2] => Josh
[3] => 1245
...
```

that prints out a table like so

```
Name    Total   Change
Mike    933     x
Josh    1245    x
```

with the following script

```
$counter = 1;
$sessionID = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
 if(++$counter % 2 === 0) {
  echo "<tr><td class='value'>".$value."</td>";
 } else {
  echo "<td class='value'>".$value."</td>";
   $sessionID++;
  echo "<td class='update'>"x"</td>";
 }
}
```

While looping I want to save the current '$value' in a session so when a user refreshes the page x will show $value - $_SESSION[$oldvalue], for example 943-933=10, and the outcome would be

```
Name    Total   Change
Mike    943     10
Josh    1045    -200
```

Hopefully you understand what I'm going after. Below is a working test version for a single user if that helps. I've tried the same idea with no luck so far.

```
$old = ($array[1] - $_SESSION["oldvalue"]);

echo "<tr><td class='value'>".$array[0]."";
echo "</td><td class='value'>".$array[1]."";

$_SESSION["oldvalue"] = $array[1];

if ($old > 100) {
 echo "</td><td class='update'>";
 echo "<b>". $old ."</b>";
} else {
 echo "</td><td class='value'>";
 echo $old;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic to the old value `943-933=10`? Why 943?

Comment: @cmnardi it was just an example. The idea is I have values X and Y, Y being the new value and X being the old value. I need to calculate the difference each time a user refreshes the page. So after each refresh the Y will change and become X while Y is a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the entire array to the session before you loop.

```
$_SESSION['old_values'] = $array;
```

Then you can compare the two arrays as you loop through, and calculate the change:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    if (!($i % 2)) {
        echo '<tr><td class="value">' . $value . '</td>';
    } else {
        $change = 'x';
        if (isset($_SESSION['old_value'][$i])) {
            $change = $_SESSION['old_value'][$i] - $value;
        }
        echo '<td class="update">' . $change . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Anyway, I think there are better ways to do what you're doing. For example, it would be preferable and far less complex if your array was structured like so:

```
[
    'Mike' => 933,
    'Josh' => 1245
]
```

---

**Test**

```
<table>
    <?php
    // Current data
    $array = ['Mike', 933, 'Josh', 1245];

    // Imagine the previous array was saved to the session:
    $_SESSION['old_value'] = ['Mike', 953, 'Josh', 1235];

    // Echo the table
    foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
        $even = !($i % 2);
        if ($even) {
            echo '<tr><td class="value">' . $value . '</td>';
        } else {
            $change = 'x';
            if (isset($_SESSION['old_value'][$i])) {
                $change = $_SESSION['old_value'][$i] - $value;
            }
            echo '<td class="update">' . $change . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }

    ?>
</table>
```

Gives:

```
Mike   20
Josh  -10
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know mine might not be the easiest solution but I just want a working version before I start improving. About your code, you are on the right track but not quite there yet. It seems the first values are saved in a session and each refresh compares the new value to the original value. So if the original value was 900 and after next refresh it is 905, the change will show +5. Ok. But if I refresh again and the value becomes 907, the change will show +7 but I need it to be +2 (after every load X becomes Y and X gets a new value). If no change happened it should be 0.

Comment: Got it working. Had to add $_SESSION['old_value'][$i] = $value; to the end of else. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, for your first question I assumed that you will update the session each time so you have the new change. It should not stay as the original values forever.

Answer (score 0):

As you loop through, set all the value's into an array, and then set the array as your $_SESSION['old_values'].

then do something like this for your output.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $value){
    $value = $value - $_SESSION['old_values'][$i];
    $i++;
}
```